# How do I center an image using jqmobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Hi i am using this piece of code to center image in jquery mobile, it centers the image in iphone simulator but when i check it on iphone, it did not exactly centers (centers itself but not exactly) itself but tends towards left.

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">

   <div id="logo_image">
       <img src="images/logo.png"  alt="Image Header" >
   </div>

</div>
```

and the css is

```
#logo_image {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left:0 auto;
  margin-right:0 auto;
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Putting "urgent please" in your title A) is noise, and B) frequently means *fewer* people will read and answer your question. I've removed it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just try `margin: 0 auto` instead of left & right margin. you'll be able to set the top and bottom margin afterwards.
greets

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `diplay: block` to your image it should position it right.

Answer (score 2):

These other answers are partially correct, but in order for the `margin: 0 auto` properties to work, I believe you also have to specify a `width` for your element.

Something like this:

```
#logo_image {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left:0 auto;
  margin-right:0 auto;
  width: 80%; 
}
```